# Android: Initial size of window, notification bar size and background image

Tags: android, portability

To improve the perceived startup time of my application, I am using an image as a drawable for my initial activity as described in
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/window-bg-speed.html
and it works wonders for what it is intended to do. The application seems to be presenting its first screen within a tenth of a second, much before my onCreate is even called.

However... My application, like most applications, should display under the notification bar of the system (it is not windowFullscreen, only windowNoTitle), and the background image I specify will take the size of the full screen, its top part going under the title bar.
My application will then start and as any well-behaved application it will display content adapted to the actual size of the viewport... which means it will not match the background image.

I could possibly leave room at the top of my startup image, but even at the same screen resolution, different devices have different size notification bars, so I can't have it fit the screen smoothly that way either - not even by supplying one image for each existing screen size, because they will have different notification bar sizes.

This happens before even the first line of code of my activity is even executed - that's the whole point of putting a background image there, to give feedback to the user as early as possible, even before the activity is actually started. The only way I can see would be to somehow tell the android framework to fit my window to the region under the bar and not the whole screen, but I couldn't find how to do that. Does anyone have an idea how to make my image closely fit the interface that will then be presented by my activity ?

Comment: I am a bit confused.  When you display the image (to fake quickstarting) it displays fine yes or no?  Or is it the real activity window that isn't displaying fine?